# Error : Gradle: Duplicate files during packaging of APK

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, spring-android

In my gradle android application when I run the application I got below error.

> Error:Gradle: duplicate files during packaging of APK /home/WorkSpace/MyProject/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk
>   Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>   Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/license.txt
>       File 1: /home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.android/spring-android-rest-template/1.0.1.RELEASE/e132d929bd181941f79b0d63edafb8a86ae6fd33/spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
>       File 2: /home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.android/spring-android-core/1.0.1.RELEASE/e68f0e8e4b636ee30c4de58953be38d9b72a5e3b/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar

Below is my gradle file.
build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
}
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


 repositories {
  jcenter()
 }

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myproject.app"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

 }
```

How I can solve this error? Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add below lines in the packagingOptions and dependencies.

```groovy
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```

And in dependencies use as below.

```groovy
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile('org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:1.0.1.RELEASE') {
    exclude module: 'spring-core'
}
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.2'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
}
```

I think this will solve your issues.

Answer (score 3):

You already have this in your build file:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
```

You can just add `license.txt` there as well.